# Can't compile GStreamer-Sharp on OS X

Tags: c#, macos, mono, gstreamer

I'm trying to use [Gst#](https://github.com/gstreamer-sharp/gstreamer-sharp) (which is the C# bindings for GStreamer) on Mac, but autotools keeps failing with these last few lines:

```
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking for pkg-config... /opt/local/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/local/bin/pkg-config
  Reason: Incompatible library version: pkg-config requires version 8.0.0 or later, but libiconv.2.dylib provides version 7.0.0
./configure: line 11558: 15968 Trace/BPT trap: 5       $PKG_CONFIG --atleast-pkgconfig-version $_pkg_min_version
no
checking for MONO_DEPENDENCY... no
checking for csc.exe... no
configure: error: You need to install either mono or .Net
```

Saying that Mono isn't installed is nonsense; how can I fix this and get it to succeed? If it helps, I installed Mono through the Mac installer, not Macports, though Macports *is* installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mono installation is not in `$PKG_CONFIG_PATH`, and that's why pkg-config cannot find the .pc files for mono.

You need to add the directory to your `$PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable. The directory should be at `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/VERSIONNUMBER/lib/pkgconfig/`

Comment: Alright, this was the other half of the issue. I wish I could accept both :P

Answer (score 1):

The error is explained quite clearly:

```
Reason: Incompatible library version: pkg-config requires version 8.0.0 or later, but libiconv.2.dylib provides version 7.0.0
```

In order to update to a newer version I would suggest trying this in `Terminal`:

```
sudo port -n upgrade --force libiconv
```

More information **[here](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/ProblemHotlist#libiconv-version)**.

Comment: Alright, fixed the libiconv error by unsetting $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, but it still doesn't think Mono is installed. Thanks for the link; one step closer!